# Magento 2 Interface Locale issue with en_gb(uk)

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, language, locale

I am using Magento 2.1.9 with  Interface Locale en_gb(uk).

After changing from english (us) to english(uk):

1. I am not able to give special date for products.
2. Not able to add cart price rules also.

Please hep me out on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this module. I've written this some time ago, but it should help or just give you hints how to solve it 
https://github.com/mmularski/magento2-locale-date-time